# Google Chrome Won't Open

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to open Google Chrome from the launcher, nothing seems to happen. (this is a new phenomenon, it used to work).  I'm on Ubuntu 13.04.

When I try to open via the terminal with either

```
google-chrome
google-chrome --incognito
```

I get,

> FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(138)] The SUID sandbox helper binary
>   was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without
>   sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that
>   /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thx.  I'm also looking through this right now http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522741

Comment: You can answer your own question so that people can find and use. I'm glad you find it.

Comment: Thx :), looks like with a very low rep score, I can't answer my own question until after 8 hours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Fixed by Mike Strand.

Cause was the ownership and permission of the sandbox files.

In this order, type the following into the terminal (`ctrl + alt + t`):

```
sudo chown root:$USER /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
```

Comment: I feel so stupid for not reading the error properly. Tks for the respose. PS: I fixed reinstaling the package.